# randc in specman

Tags: specman

How do you generate "randc" kind of implementation using gen in specman?
**Example:**

```
list_l : list of uint(bits:3);
keep list_1.size () == 8;
```

I want to generated in such a way that all the elements of the list should have the random no between (0 -7).

Answer (score 2):

The constraints currently defined on the list will ensure that the list is generated with all values in the range `[0..7]`.
Using `gen` will generate the list as required.

**Example**

```
list_l : list of uint(bits:3);
keep list_l.size () == 8;
generate_list() is {
    gen list_l;
}
```

If you would like all list items to be unique, add the following constraint on the list:

```
keep list_l.all_differnt(it);
```

Comment: To elaborate on what alpeka was saying, each element of `list_l` will be between 0 and 7, because Specman knows what the range of a `uint(bits:3)` is.  If you need to constraint the elements in a list to a subset of the numbers allowed by the data type, you can do something like: `keep for each (e) in list_l) { e in [1..3,5..6];  };`

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use the **"is_a_permutation()"** pseudo-method in order to populate the list with each value once.

**Example**

```
list_l : list of uint(bits:3);
keep list_1.is_a_permutation(all_values(uint(bits:3)));
```

or

```
keep list_1.is_a_permutation({0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7});
```

Note that in this example **"is_a_permutation()"** constraints the list-size to be exactly 8.